# ms-access 2007 Report's

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

Good Day

newbie to reports in ms-access 2007.

created form and a combo-box listing names. a sub-data-sheet with minor details to the item selected in combo-box.
just needed to know, How to create a report based on this from...

When I create a report all information is displayed, I only need selected info from that form

Thanks A mil.

Comment: Vote to close, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1327272/ms-access-2007-creating-report-based-on-a-multi-tables-form

Answer (score 0):

Let's say the name of the form is fMyForm and you have named the combo box cboCriteria, and lets say the field is MyField.  Choose yes for the filterOn property of the report and in the filter for the report put [MyField]=forms!fMyForm!cboCriteria